# What are some of these directories in the Linux kernel src?

Tags: kernel

When I uncompress the Linux kernel source code from Kernel.org, there are many folders. I know what most of them contain and their purpose. However, I cannot figure out or find on the Internet the purpose for the tools, samples, and block directories. What are these three directories and what is their purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured out that the block folder contains source code for block-device drivers, samples is example programming, and tools contains tools for interacting with the kernel.

Comment: The samples folder also contains modules that were started, but no maintainer has taken over. New kernel developers can look through here for a module that they would like to develop for the Linux Kernel team.